# Doubt with CTRL pin for the power module VRB2405S-6WR3

Tags: power-modules

I want to use the DC-DC power module for my project. Datasheet for the module is available at the following link.

https://www.mornsun-power.com/public/uploads/pdf/VRB_S-6WR3.pdf

This module uses a `Ctrl` pin control secondary on/off for the module. However, I don't know its impedance. I have the following circuit in my mind to control the module. I need your guidance to see if it is the right way or not. Specially with the `150k ohm` part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2wImm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update: (Circuit suggested by @jsotola)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52tQt.png)</sup>

Comment: the datasheet implies that the CTRL input has an internal pullup, as per top of page 2

Comment: Yes, So to control with 3.3V, the circuit I presented in the question is correct. Am I right?

Comment: it should work ... pullup resistor may not be necessary

Comment: @jsotola, I got it. I updated the question. Please see if that is how you are suggesting. Thank you.